# Is this an intelligent usecase of Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to build an intelligent field mapper and would like to know whether Optaplanner is the correct fit. The requirement is as follows

1. I have a UI which accept source and target xml field schema.
2. The source and target schema contains multiple business fields which can be further classified to multiple business groups. There will be certain rules (which we can consider as constraints as per optaplanner) which needs to be considered during the field mapping. The objective of the tool is to find the field mapping ( Each source field needs to find its best fit target field)

Can optaplanner be used to solve this problem ? I'm confused whether this is a mathematical optimzation problem or a machine learning predictive model problem (For this to work, i need to work on building sufficient labelled mapping data )

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head, there are 3 potential situations to be in, going from easy to hard:

A) You can use a decision table to figure the mapping decision. Don't use OptaPlanner, use Drools.

B) Given two mapping proposals, you can score which one is better, through a formal scoring function. Use OptaPlanner.

C) You don't know your scoring function in detail yet. You have some vague ideas. You want to use training data of historical decisions to build one. Don't use OptaPlanner, use Machine Learning.